# Karma AngularJS mock JSON file which loads before angular.bootstrap

Tags: json, angularjs, mocking, karma-jasmine

My application loads a JSON file with the configuration before running *app.run()*.

```
function loadConfig(options) {
  var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  var $http = $injector.get('$http');

  function validate(data) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error('Error in ' + options.cfgUri);
      return false;
    }
  }

  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: options.cfgUri,
    transformResponse: validate
  }).then(response => {app.constant('$config', response.data || {})}, response => {throw new Error(response)}));
}

function startApp() {
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });
}

loadConfig({
  cfgUri: 'config/config.json'
}).then(startApp);
```

The question is, can I somehow mock this JSON file taking into account the fact it's required in any test within a project?

Right now I don't manage this and just get a **JSON.parse** error in the tests beginning.

Comment: u can mock angular.injector function before u run mock.module, but actually I think that using $http before bootstraping angular is antipattern -- I suggest you to re-work this

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, I understand this is the anti-pattern perhaps, but there is nothing I can do about it, I can't refactor this area of code. The problem is that I don't know where to locate the code mocking angular-injector, since it's not related to any specific spec, but to the whole project, like a prerequisite, and just for this segment of the code. BTW, I could better mocked $http behaviour to give a fake JSON file as a response